# How to bypass isFromMockProvider

Tags: java, android, apk, smali

I tried to edit source code of an app which is used to locate servants It has a function or parameter `isFromMockProvider()` I guess this one is the culprit

I want to bypass it So that App could not know that I am using Mock location.

I am a python dev not know enough about Smali Please Help.. Thank You..

```smali
method public static final isMocked(Landroid/location/Location;)Z

    .locals 2

    const-string v0, "<this>"

    invoke-static {p0, v0}, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;->checkNotNullParameter(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    sget v0, Landroid/os/Build$VERSION;->SDK_INT:I

    const/16 v1, 0x1f

    if-lt v0, v1, :cond_0

    .line 200

    invoke-static {p0}, Lcom/free/freeapp/ui/RouteStepView$$ExternalSyntheticApiModelOutline0;->m(Landroid/location/Location;)Z

    move-result p0

    goto :goto_0

    .line 202

    :cond_0

    invoke-virtual {p0}, Landroid/location/Location;->isFromMockProvider()Z

    move-result p0

    :goto_0

    return p0

.end method
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the result of the call `isFromMockProvider()`then you have to look at these two lines:

```
invoke-virtual {p0}, Landroid/location/Location;->isFromMockProvider()Z

move-result p0
```

The first line calls the method `isFromMockProvider()`, the second stores the return value of the call into register `p0`.

Then `p0`is later returned as return value of `isMocked(Location)`.

If you want to prevent your mocked locations from being recognized you need to let `isMocked(Location)` false (which is `0` in Smali as there is no special boolean type).

The easiest way is to leave everything as it is and just ignore the return value of `isFromMockProvider()`. So instead of the two lines presented in the first code block of this post we use this one:

```
invoke-virtual {p0}, Landroid/location/Location;->isFromMockProvider()Z

# move-result p0 # line is commented out

const/4 p0, 0x0 # write false=0 into p0
```